# Can a machine be something that hasn't been conciously built?

Tags: meaning

I've stumbled upon quite some papers and articles that refer to cellular processes as "machineries".

Aren't machines/machineries supposed to be devices that have been consciously built to execute a specific task?

This would exclude cellular processes from being called machines, as they weren't built with a concrete purpose in mind, but instead selected for over a time frame of millions of years.

Comment: Can you show us a dictionary description that includes 'consciously'?

Comment: And sometimes etymology comes home to roost. [organism:1895 definition](https://books.google.com/books/content?id=sPJgjK5QvEUC&pg=PR17&img=1&zoom=3&hl=en&sig=ACfU3U3U4ArdGJwLNnAaUdCvmwjkraMeyQ&ci=57%2C1002%2C833%2C148&edge=0)

Comment: Try a [dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Machine) definition first and then look up [simple machines](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_machine). The word "machine" has a broad definition and conscious isn’t always implied.

Answer (score 1):

**Understanding cellular machineries** [cellular machineries](http://www.crg.eu/en/news/understanding-cellular-machineries)

> Cellular **machineries** are ensembles of intracellular players that,
>   together, ensure and control the function of a cell and regulate the
>   architecture of multicellular tissues.

**machine** in this sense:  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/machine)

> An intricate natural system or organism, such as the human body.

Thus:

> This would include cellular processes as machines.

Comment: I understand that the dictionary allows for using the word in this way. My question was more whether or not this use is accepted common parlance. To me, it seems weird to merge the creations of nature and the conscious creations of man in the same word.